# Unable to to send Image data via AJAx to servlet

Tags: ajax, servlets, post, base64

I am using the following AJAX code to send data to servlet. I am unable to figure out why the data is not being sent. The servlet gets invoked, but the data is null. This is base 64 encoded image data from HTML canvas.

```
  $.ajax({
  contentType: 'text/plain',

  data: {
      'image': uri

  },
  dataType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  success: function(data){
      alert("Success");
          },
  error: function(){
      alert("Sorry failure");
      // callback in case of error
  },
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'SaveImageServlet'
  });
```

Server side code looks like

```
String imageData = request.getParameter("image");
```

The base64 encoded data is there as I print it to an alert. So that is not the issue.

Comment: You can't force your browser to download files with Javascript, if that's what you were trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The AJAX issue never got solved. However, I found a way to send the base64 image data to the servlet. Just appended it to hidden field and sent it as a regular form field.